# I have user that belongs to another azure active directory, and I want to add them to my azure active directory as users

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I would like to add users from another azure active directory organization to my azure active directory organization.  The problem is the other organization does not want to open up their azuread for b2b collaboration due to security reasons.  Can these users with their email addresses from the other organization still be added as guest users to my azuread?  Or will the domain of their email address or the azuread they belong to by it stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can these users with their email addresses from the other organization
>   still be added as guest users to my azuread?

If you're trying to add users from other organization as **Guest Users** to your Azure AD, then I think yes you should be able to invite them. Whether the invite is redeemed or not is up to the user I think.

> Or will the domain of their email address or the azuread they belong
>   to by it stop this from happening?

AFAIK, all the collaboration settings for an Azure AD that only control which users can be added to that particular organization and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add local users with a domain that isn't a verified domain in your tenant.

Comment: I am able to add ***@gmail.com as guest user.  Is this because gmail is automatically a verified domain?

Comment: @juunas I know you're an expert on Azure AD and I've learnt from your posts and blogs on multiple occasions. In this particular case though, may be you've misunderstood the question.. I agree with your statement `No, you can't add local users with a domain that isn't a verified domain in your tenant.` but if idea is to just invite a user from another Azure AD organization as a guest user, why would that not be possible? I may be completely off here, so please feel free to correct me in case I got something wrong.

Comment: Well the whole point of the question was that the other org doesn't want to open up B2B collaboration. So yes, you can add them if you use the B2B invitation mechanism. But not as local users (non-external).

Comment: At least that's how I understood it :)